# Magento 1.9.2. - Get Admin value of attribute option in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attributes, eav

I'm trying to recall in my configurable product the value of the 'color' attribute of the products associated with the foreach method:

`foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
echo "$simple_product->getAttributeText('color')";
}`

But with this method it shows the value of the attribute in its current language and not of the admin. I attach a picture for this.

[image]

How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$simple_product->getData('color')
```

Will give you **option_id**, then you can retrieve Admin label, for instance, this way...

```
$option = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setStoreFilter(0)
    ->setIdFilter($optionId);
```

You can do `print_r($option->getData())` to see available data. Don't remember right now, but I think just "label" will give you what you want, as collection is filtered by Admin store

Comment: With my foreach I directly pull out the value of the color attribute that assigned to a product. This method in my foreach unfortunately  is not good. Exist another way?